# why won't my loop continue in windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I have made this windows forms app where I get a value from a serial port and translates it to a string which it displays in a text box. Or is supposed to at least.

It seems as though something is preventing my code from looping, and thus do not work as intended.

If I set the `myOrderedDictionary.Add (55, 33)` Value to an int from the `ConverterDictionary` I print the corresponding string once but then it stops. I changed this cause I don't want it to display something right away. Instead, only when all of the Values from `myOrderedDictionary` is the same.

I am quite certain that the if statement in displaydata_event is messing with me since I got the in_data output on loop before I put them in. But I don't know why it is only going through the method only once, and what I can do about it?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort myport;
    private string in_data;
    string TheSign { get; set; }
    public bool statemnt = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class ConverterDictionary
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> Dict { get; }   
        public ConverterDictionary()
        {
            Dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
            {44, "Hey!"},
            {53, "Bye!"},
            {57, "Wazza!"}
            };
        }
    }

    private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 9600;
        myport.PortName = port_name_tb.Text;
        myport.Parity = Parity.None;
        myport.DataBits = 8;
        myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        myport.DataReceived += myport_DataReceived;
        try {
            myport.Open();
            data_tb.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    void myport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        OrderedDictionary myOrderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary(4);
        myOrderedDictionary.Add(55, 33);
        myOrderedDictionary.Add(65, 22);
        myOrderedDictionary.Add(75, 11);

        var pos0 = myOrderedDictionary[0];
        var pos1 = myOrderedDictionary[1];
        var pos2 = myOrderedDictionary[2];

        int data1;
        int data2;
        int data3;

        data1 = Convert.ToInt32(pos0);
        data2 = Convert.ToInt32(pos1);
        data3 = Convert.ToInt32(pos2);

        ICollection keyCollection = myOrderedDictionary.Keys;
        ICollection valueCollection = myOrderedDictionary.Values;

        in_data = myport.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));

        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            myOrderedDictionary.Insert(0, i, in_data);
            myOrderedDictionary.RemoveAt(3);

            if (i >= 19)
            {
                i = 1;
            }
        }
        if (data1 == data2 && data2 == data3)
        {
            TheSign = new ConverterDictionary().Dict[data1];
            statemnt = true;
        }
    }
    private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        data_tb.AppendText("\n" + in_data);
        if (statemnt == true)
        {
            data_tb.AppendText("\n" + in_data);
            dict_tb.Text = TheSign + "\n";
            statemnt = false;
        }
        else
        {
            data_tb.AppendText("\n" + in_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is infinite... once it starts, it will never complete or `break`.

Comment: yes, I know that. Let me rephrase Something in my code, blocks it from continuing to loop. Hence I get the in_data printed in the data_tb twice before it stops. I have not included anything in my code that would do this (to my knowledge). Therefore I am looking for a way to get the results that I want (as stated in the OP).

Comment: @Fladderkatt Your `for` loop blocks it.

Comment: @rdmodulator Thank you! Any idea how I can add names to the keys instead so they won't interfere with each other? Since I cannot add a key with the same name as another one.

Comment: @Fladderkatt I don't think a `Dictionary` is the best choice. There's a lot of things going on here and I don't understand the "why?" behind them.